# Cannot set property.com.android.ide.eclipse.adt:state to

Tags: android, events, for-loop

I am getting this error after every 1-2 mins when i open the eclipse editor.I downloaded new eclipse still i get the same error with the new eclipse installed.This has been very frustating.Does any 1 have any knowledge about it.I am using eclipse kepler

Error Log:
Cannot set property com.android.ide.eclipse.adt:state to 3.7" WVGA (Nexus One):Portrait::+AppTheme::notnight::com.example.veri_yolla.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment
Unhandlend event loop exception